# UIKit navbar not dropping down

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, getuikit

I have a UIkit navbar but the dropdown won't work. I have seen a similar post on here that suggested jquery may be the problem, but I have tried installing jquery in all the ways I can think. That being said, it does seem like a javascript issue. I am currently happily using jquery in the app though. I am using webpacker, and I see that uikit and uikit icons are present on the sources tab of the chrome debugger.
This is the haml and generated html:

```
%nav#navbar.uk-navbar-container.uk-navbar
  #logo.uk-navbar-left
    Logo
  #user-navbar.uk-navbar-right
    - if user_signed_in?
      %ul.uk-navbar-nav
        %li.uk-parent
          %a{href: '#'} #{current_user.display_name}
          .uk-navbar-dropdown
            %ul.uk-nav.uk-navbar-dropdown-nav
              %li
                = link_to 'Sign out', '/users/sign_out', :method => :delete
```

```
<nav class="uk-navbar-container uk-navbar" id="navbar">
  <div class="uk-navbar-left" id="logo">
    Logo
  </div>
  <div class="uk-navbar-right" id="user-navbar">
    <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
      <li class="uk-parent">
        <a href="#">Should Dropdown</a>
        <div class="uk-navbar-dropdown">
          <ul class="uk-nav uk-navbar-dropdown-nav">
            <li>
              <a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out">Sign out</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

It seems to me that it follows the example here: https://getuikit.com/docs/navbar#usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this SHOULD WORK :

```html
<!-- UIkit CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.5.9/dist/css/uikit.min.css" />

<!-- UIkit JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.5.9/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.5.9/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<nav class="uk-navbar-container" uk-navbar>
    <div class="uk-navbar-left">

       
    Logo


    </div>
    <div class="uk-navbar-right">
        <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Should Dropdown</a>
                <div class="uk-navbar-dropdown">
                    <ul class="uk-nav uk-navbar-dropdown-nav">
                         <a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out">Sign out</a>
                        
                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: i just post the html that work for me , can you post more informations !!

Comment: Sorry, actually you were right! I had included uk-navbar as a class, but not as an attribute.Thank you!